# jQuery get first children of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my html

```
<div class="start">
    <div> <!-- this -->
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div></div> <!-- this -->
    <div> <!-- this -->
        <div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    <div>
<div>
```

I need to collect all the selected `div`, and I can do it with `$('div[class="start"] > div')`, but how to do it in a `.each()` cycle, because I'm cycling on all the `div[class="start"]'`.

```
$('div[class="start"]').each(function(){
    doSomething($(this));
    //this below is what I want to achieve
    $(this).children('> div').each(function(){
         doSomethingElse($(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you need **Index** here. Try `$('div[class="start"]').each(function(index, value) ...`. When `index == 0`, it's your first element

Comment: Use find() instead of children()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is more or less correct but instead of children() you need to use find()

```
$('div[class="start"]').each(function(){
    doSomething($(this));
    //this below is what I want to achieve
    $(this).find('> div').each(function(){
         doSomethingElse($(this));
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/swmdan5h/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `children`

```
$('div.start').children().each(function() {
```

This will select all the direct children of the `div` having class `start`.

There is no need of using attribute-value selector here, you can use class selector.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `>` or `> div`

```
$('div[class="start"]').each(function(){
    doSomething($(this));
    //this below is what I want to achieve
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        doSomethingElse($(this));
    });
});
```